# Convergence of Alternating harmonic series (Direct!)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, alternative-proof

[image]

Once again, note No use of the alternating series test!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly:
write $A_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k}$. You want to show that $(A_n)_n$ is a converging sequence. It is enough to show that both $(A_{2n})_n$ and $(A_{2n+1})_n$ converge, and that $A_{2n+1}-A_{2n}\to 0$. The last part is trivial as $A_{2n+1}-A_{2n} = -\frac{1}{2n+1}$; the first two are done in a similar (almost identical) way:
$$
A_{2n+1} = -1 + \sum_{k=1}^n \left( \frac{1}{2k} - \frac{1}{2k+1}\right) = -1 + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k(2k+1)}
$$
Since $\frac{1}{2k(2k+1)}\operatorname*{\sim}_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{4k^2}$, this last series converges.

Comment: Could you explain a bit why these steps work? I don't have any reasoning behind why it is enough to do just this nor why this shows convergence.

Comment: If $(u_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is a sequence, $u_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\ell$ if and only if ($u_{2n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\ell$ and $u_{2n+1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\ell$). (this is a special case of a more general statement which says that a sequence converges iff all its subsequences converge to the same limit; see eg [this](http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/R.W.Kaye/seqser/subsequences2))

Comment: I also don't follow your odd sequence that equals series addition listed there near the end. if you check A3 for example they aren't equal.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry -- there was a $-1$ term missing (the $-1/(2k+1)$ term didn't cover $-1/1$, as this would need $k=0$ which is not in the summation)

Comment: Is their a concrete way that you came to that sequence equation for odd termed subsequences? Cause it still seems like we are assuming that holds for all odds without showing that it does.

Comment: When you write $A_{2n+1}$, you get 
$$
A_{2n+1} = \sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} \frac{(-1)^k}{k} = \sum_{\substack{1\leq k \leq 2n+1\\ k\text{ even}}} \frac{1}{k} - \sum_{\substack{1\leq k \leq 2n+1\\ k\text{ odd}}} \frac{1}{k} = \sum_{\substack{1\leq 2i \leq 2n+1}} \frac{1}{2i} - \sum_{\substack{1\leq 2i+1 \leq 2n+1}} \frac{1}{2i+1}
$$
which leads to the expression above by merging the two sums.

Comment: It is just needed to show that the two subsequences converge to the same limit. You could have $u_{2n}$ and $u_{2n+1}$ both converging, but to different values (take $u_n=(-1)^n$, for instance), in which case $(u_n)_n$ does not converge.

Comment: Doesn't this assume that you can re-arrange the terms of the sequence (namely, group with parentheses opportunistically)?

Comment: Not in that case: it's not an arbitrary rearrangement.